# Why does Win7 show less wireless networks than WifiInfoView

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

The usual way to scan for wireless networks, which is located in the taskbar in win 7 shows only a few networks, but when I scan with the Freeware [WifiInfoView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) I find 8 or more.

[Image to clarify](https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pl/wifi.png/_341eabfaf09e490b990c57e73eff1244)

Why doesn't windows display the same amount when it uses the same network adapter?
Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: isn't it that WifiInfoView shows several times the "same" network because there are several access points sharing the same SSID?

Comment: That is true but cannot be the only reason because sometimes windows shows only 2 networks while WifiInfoView shows way more that do not all have the same name

Answer (score 0):

I guess Windows shows the four strongest networks, and leaves the rest out of view. If you press the refresh button in the top right corner, it might show the other ones. I don't use Windows 7, but I can imagine that if you open the network center, more networks are shown?

Comment: Could be, but then how would you explain that sometimes a network disappears for a short time?
But you are right in that the refresh-button makes some networks appear - sometimes, but sometimes it makes some disappear. It seems random to me.

Comment: Wireless signals are random. Its inherent in how it works. A sack of water (a body) gets between your laptop and the AP and you can get a degradation of signal. AP might not send a signal the same strength all around it. Signal might bounce off walls.

Comment: It might be that Windows does some filtering on the displayed networks, but I'm not sure there is such a low threshold for the count of networks. It would be a very bad idea, in some corporate environments you might have more than 4 networks... plus the surrounding ones.

Comment: Where I live I can see about 20 networks on my Mac. It shows the ones you have used before on top, the rest is based on strength.

Comment: Thank you SPRBRN, but that doesn't help me because I have win7...can anybody with win7 check how many networks it shows them? Maybe it's just my pc